# Problem installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, rsync

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in my Dell Vostro 3546, which already has Windows 8 on it. I have a 320GB HDD with 2GB RAM.

I am using a bootable USB drive to this. All goes well for the first part. I choose my language, connect to WiFi and select the option to install third party software and updates. Then there is the option about whether to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 or something else.

Whenever I choose the "install alongside" option and press continue, the installation exits to a black screen showing the following text:

```
wait-for-state stop/waiting
* Stopping rsync daemon rsync
* speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
* Asking all remaining processes to terminate ...
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: I guess you can try installing without connecting to WiFi and installing updates.

Comment: That message is usually seen during a verbose shut down or a shut down through the terminal. I think there's either something wrong with your Ubuntu install media or possibly the automatic creation of the second partition for Ubuntu. I've read that Windows 8 puts its important files in the middle of that partition, which makes resizing difficult. You may have to do it manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the perfect dual-boot between Windows-Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/567932/how-to-install-the-perfect-dual-boot-between-windows-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

In my installation of Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Win 8, I ended up 
having to create the partitions for Ubuntu from the Windows side 
using 'Disk Management'. If your 320GB HD is all utilized for Windows
you will need to do this as well. Set up at least 2 partitions, one for /
and a swap partition, formatting as FAT32. 
  Now when you begin the Ubuntu install, there are now empty partitions
that can be chosen as the drive to install Ubuntu into (/)and the swap
partition. Ubuntu will look for drives and after found you can simply
answer questions to tell where install takes place and filesystem to 
set up (I used ext4). Hope this helps Craig

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced same problem, while I was trying to install Ubuntu 14.0 alongside with Windows 7

```
wait-for-state stop/waiting
* Stopping rsync daemon rsync
* speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
* Asking all remaining processes to terminate ...
```

Tried to leave unallocated or free space next to the `C:` drive, further proceeded with the Ubuntu installation as dual boot. It now worked fine.